# How to query facebook with FQL to get usernames who liked and commented on a post or a photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Ok what i want to do is simple but i am not sure it can be done or not

Here my post and image that i want to query

Original share image :

https://www.facebook.com/MonsterMMORPG/photos/a.551985868170404.1073741825.198765706825757/694573437244979/?type=1

The reshare of the image

https://www.facebook.com/MonsterMMORPG/posts/699889243380065

Now i want to get people who liked image and post and also commented on them

I am trying to get userids of who liked via FQL like below but it returns nothing

```
SELECT user_id  FROM like WHERE post_id=699889243380065
```

I am doing this at graph api explorer panel here screenshot

first image works second fails

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook-graph-api to get your list of likes, as follows:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/699889243380065/likes

(with valid tokens of course)

You'll receive the following list:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "xxx", 
      "name": "xxx"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "xxx", 
      "name": "xxx"
    }, 
etc
```

To get list of comments via graph-api:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/699889243380065/comments